# Pygame pygame.error: Error reading from ICO

Tags: python, image, compiler-errors, pygame, icons

I have a project that uses pygame, and at the beginning, it uses pygame to change the title and icon as well as setup the screen, and for some reason, I keep getting the same error when I try to set the icon, I have tried this with bmp, jpg, ico, and png. All give the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programming\Python\Python 3.6.2\RoboCart LED Controller\RC_CTRL11.py", line 87, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\Programming\Python\Python 3.6.2\RoboCart LED Controller\RC_CTRL11.py", line 7, in main
    screen = initDisp()
  File "D:\Programming\Python\Python 3.6.2\RoboCart LED Controller\RC_CTRL11.py", line 80, in initDisp
    icon = pygame.image.load('progIcon.ico')
pygame.error: Error reading from ICO
```

The code that I am using, which produces the error could be found in this function:

```
def initDisp():
    # Init pygame to the screen resolution
    global RESOLUTION
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(RESOLUTION)
    pygame.display.set_caption("ROBO_CTRL11")
    icon = pygame.image.load('progIcon.ico')
    pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
    return screen
```

This may be  a dumb question with a simple answer, and I hope it is because I could not find very much online. P.S. all of the pictures I have tried are in the current directory of the python file.

P.P.S: A unit test for the problem is below:

```
import pygame

def main():
    screen = initDisp()

def initDisp():
    # Init pygame to the screen resolution
    RESOLUTION = (420, 380)
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(RESOLUTION)
    pygame.display.set_caption("ROBO_CTRL11")
    icon = pygame.image.load('progIcon.ico')
    pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
    return screen

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Attached are the photos I am trying to use, all the formats.
[Icon Photos](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B83X7aD80EzRTXRKUnRvZ014bHM)

Comment: It seems the `.ico` format is [not supported](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html), but it should work with the other formats. Try it again with a jpg or png and double check if the name and the file extension are spelled correctly.

Comment: I have double checked the file names and extensions, and it has given me the same result

Comment: Could you post a [minimal, runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the image?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and my solution was to add the path regardless of the fact that it is in the same dir as the program (\ instead of \ in the path).

like this-

`icon = pygame.image.load("C:\\Users\\User\\DesktopAppIcon.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)`

Answer (score 0):

First I want to note I got a different error message than you, since you got a `pygame.error: Error reading from ICO` while I got a `pygame.error: Unsupported ICO bitmap format`. Having said that, I solved it by using PIL to convert from the ico file to RGBA bytes:

```py
import pygame, PIL.Image
Window = pygame.display.set_mode((200, 200))
Icon = PIL.Image.open("path.ico")
Icon = Icon.tobytes(), Icon.size, Icon.mode
pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.frombytes(*Icon))
```